# Variables globales con kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hola estoy intentando usar una variable de un actividad, en otra.
Intente con "intent", pero al parecer esto solo funciona si la recepción de la información en la Activity destino se realiza siempre dentro del método onCreate(), en mi caso no pasa eso, por ello no puedo utilizar esta opción.
Otra opción seria creando una clase con variables globales, cuales son los pasos para crearla y llamar a las variables desde cualquier actividad.

Comment: Procura incluir en tus preguntas un poco de contexto sobre tu caso y muestra todo el código que creas pueda ser relevante. Tal vez lo que estás intentando hacer es una mala práctica y podemos darte alternativas. Creo que te estás perdiendo de muchas respuestas simplemente porque tus preguntas no son lo suficientemente claras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que la forma más apropiada es con un Intent pero es dificil de decir si no nos cuentas que tipo de información quieres pasar. Esta se puede recibir a partir del método `onCreate`, no necesariamente dentro del mismo. Por ejemplo podrías hacer esto:

```
class ExampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val args by lazy { intent.extras }
}
```

Tambíen puedes crear un companion object para tener variables que sean accesibles desde cualquier parte:

```
class ExampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        var example = "ExampleActivity.example"
    }
}
```

O bien crear un singleton completo:

```
object GlobalVars {
    var example = "GlobalVars.example"
}
```

Esos son ejemplos básicos, hay más formas pero no sé si vale la pena explicarlas sin conocer tu caso de uso.

Si tu proyecto es simple puede que no necesites crear más de una activity. Podrías tener una MainActivty y cambiar las vistas usando Fragments. Esto se llama "single activity pattern" y es la arquitectura recomendada por google. Siguiendo esta arquitectura desarrollaron el [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) que te facilita la navegación y comunicación entre vistas. Incluso hay un plugin para este componente llamado [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) que vuelve esta tarea aun más fácil.

Además puedes pasar información entre fragments compartiendo un ViewModel:

```
class ExampleFragment: Fragment() {
    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<ExampleViewModel>()
}
```

Por ultimo, me gustaría mencionar que si la informacion que estás pasando es algo que podría servirte la proxima vez que se inicie la app, lo correcto es usar las SharedPreferences:

```
// guardar
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit { putString("example", "value") }
// recibir
var example = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .getString("example", "defaultValue")
```

Comment: Con "companion object" pude lograrlo

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudarte. Podrías marcar la respuesta como correcta?